# Check whether any cells in a given range have a value equal to the string

Tags: vba, function, excel, boolean-expression

How do I create a boolean function that searches cells in a range and checks if any have a value equal to the specified string? If so, it returns true. If not, it returns false.

This is as far as I've gotten

```
Function NameExist(ByVal Name as String, NameRange as Range) As Boolean
Boolean as NameExist = False
If (Name = Michael) Then
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one implementation:

```
Function NameExists(ByVal searchName As String, nameRange As Range) As Boolean
    NameExists = Not nameRange.Find(What:=searchName, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Here's another, more manual / brute force one:

```
Function NameExists(ByVal searchName As String, nameRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    v = nameRange.Value
    NameExists = False
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            If v(i, j) = searchName Then
                NameExists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

Both should give the same results.

Example usage:

```
If NameExists("Michael",range("B3:C6")) Then MsgBox "Michael exists!"
```